# How to show user that backend task is in process

Tags: android

In my application I have an account activation form, which gets authenticated via Internet.IN the mean time (after the activate button is click)I wish to show some sort of UI to the user so that he knows that activation is in progress. Please can u share the code with me.
Also how do I create a successful file after the app is activated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
You can provide your own loading layout while a thread is executing in the background. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Async task like this

declare a progress dialog before OnCreate

ProgressDialog dialog;

and add a class extended with AsyncTask like

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // perform the action which you want to do

            return null;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
 {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation

  // perform task which you want to display once background task is finished 

            dialog.dismiss();


        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

// initialize dialog 

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Comment.this);

// set message 
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait while processing");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
         */
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)

        {

        }

    }
```

can refer this link also,

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask

Comment: Thanks for the solution.Also how do I create a successful file after the app is activated(Any text/dat file.. any thing would do)

Comment: dialog=new ProgressDialog(Activate.activateContext);


NPE here.. :(

Comment: actually this might be due to wrong context , decalre it like         dialog = new ProgressDialog(your_activity_name.this);

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `AsyncTask` to complete this, I assume that you read the documentation. if not I can provide you with an example:

```
public void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   publishProgress(i);
  }
}
```

from the `doInBackground` method publish the progress to the `onProgressUpdate` method

```
   public void onProgressUpdate(int arg0) {
       Log.d(arg0);
    }
```